# Backward chaining Jena reasoner

Tags: rdf, jena, jena-rules

I have been reading through the Jena documentation in order to try and create a simple pure backward chaining reasoner. I have a simple backward chaining rule that I am applying to a small ontology.
I was wondering if there was anyway to do backward chaining on a per query basis, so that not all of the entailments are computed when I get my InfModel with:

```java
Modelfactory.createInfModel(reasoner,model)
```

but rather only when they are requested. So, for the rule below:

```
[rule2: (?x rdfs:type ?z)<-(?x ?rdf:type ?y),(?y rdfs:subClassOf ?z)]
```

could I register a query asking to find all types of a particular class, which would then fire the above rule?

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yes I was satisfied with the answer I got but I think my question was slightly off the mark. I was aware that Jena allowed you to run reasoners in a full backward more, it's just not very obvious that it's doing so as when you write out the inference model it returns raw + deductions graph. To me this seemed like it was doing some forward chaining reasoning, but if you call .size() on the inference graph you will actually see that its size correlates to the raw graph. So no reasoning has in fact been done before the write command, which must mean write counts as a query.

Comment: Write essentially has to ask for all triples, which is like asking the model to list statements matching `(null,null,null)`, so it's not just that write counts as a query, but that write must run a query in order to get the triples that it needs to write. The docs on Model.size() say that "for a virtualized model such as one created by an inference engine, it will return an estimated lower bound for the numberof statements in the model but it is possible for a subsequent listStatements on such a model to discover more statements than size() indicated," which is the behavior you have seen.

Comment: If you want to write out just the triples that have already been inferred, you can use InfModel.getDeductionsModel, the model returned by which you should be able write out without additional querying.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation on the backward chaining engine](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/#RULEbackward), the behavior that you want is already what the backward chaining engine provides:

> If the rule reasoner is run in backward chaining mode it uses a logic programming (LP) engine with a similar execution strategy to Prolog engines. *When the inference Model is queried then the query is translated into a goal and the engine attempts to satisfy that goal* by matching to any stored triples and by goal resolution against the backward chaining rules. [emphasis added]

If you define a reasoner with the rule that you provided, then when you ask for triples of the form `x rdf:type z`, the reasoner will, at that time, fire that rule.

Comment: Yes I read this, but it confuses me. Do you know what sort of query they are talking about? Is it just performing a simple get(triple) on the model. When I compute the inference model using getInfGraph, all entailments seem to be computed prior to any query I execute. Which I find quite strange.

Comment: @user2370200 Hmm… yes, I am playing with some backwards rule sets now, and I see the behavior that you are talking about.  It seems like Jena is figuring out which values to instantiate the head of the rule with, and then running the query.  I'm not sure exactly what is happening here, but I will continue to investigate.

Comment: I think I have made progress. I called .size on my infgraph and found that the size indicated that no entailments are derived when my reasoner is bound to the model, this is leading me to believe that when I call the .write method that this is considered as a query.

Comment: @user2370200 (I erased the previous comment; it wasn't well thought out, and was misleading.)  In Prolog, one can ask queries that include variables, and get back as many answers as the system can compute.  As the documentation describes, the triples in backward chaining rules can be thought of as using an implicit `triple` predicate, where `(?s ?p ?o)` is actually `triple(?s,?p,?o)`.  Asking for all statements (which `write` has to do) is like asking `triple(S,P,O)`, and of course the head of the rule will match, and you'll get the closure of the inferences.